# How to add specific character using sed anywhere

Tags: shell-script, sed

here is my shell-script file to executed using gradle.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello world"
jar=$(ls ./Test/Web/build/libs/)
echo " "
echo "$jar"


sed -i "s|build/libs/.*|build/libs/$jar|g" ./Test/build.gradle
```

This script is producing  following output with sed operation
'build/libs/Web-5.0.0-2-dev.jar

Only thing missing from above output is single quotation ' at the end of the line.

i want output to be like below line

'build/libs/Web-5.0.0-2-dev.jar'

other-wise gradle will through error

So how to  add that specific character at the end of the above output 
Or could we add something to existing sed operation to get the desired result.

Comment: I don't know what in your `./Test/build.gradle` is, but note `.` can match `'`. If `build/libs/.*` matches anything, then it matches to the end of the line. Is `'` always in the input file? If so, the replacement may be `build/libs/$jar'`. Still [some implementations of `ls` may add quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/108618) or such; `ls` is not the right tool here. Side issue: what if `ls` returns more or less than one file? Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). You don't want to add a character. You want to replace some path(s) in the file.

Comment: that build.gradle file has a line 'build/libs/Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar', above sed operation is removing everything after 'build/libs/ with variable which doesn't have that single quotation, and yeah i know that 'ls' will be problematic if it returns more than one file. I am exploring other possible options to get that file name.

Comment: i used below command to get desired result.                                                                           sed -i "s|build/libs/.*|build/libs/$jar\'|g" ./Test/build.gradle